# Orientation mode: Show Portrait once and then as per device oreinetation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

For Android app, I want to show the Landing screen of my app in Portrait mode every time it is launched, irrespective of device orientation.

However, later on when Activity/Fragment is fully launched, it should support both landscape and portrait mode as per device orientation.

Comment: what do you mean by landing screen. Is it a splash screen ?

Comment: @John Landing screen is the first screen shown in my app.

Comment: I assume ,you want to set the first screen to portrait initially and change the first screen's orientation to as per device orientation. Right ?

Comment: @John: Exactly. When first screen is shown to user, and then when user changes the device orientation, the screen should rotate!

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

to set it to portrait and then use

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`

once your landing screen is done to allow both orientations again.

Comment: How to know that landing screen is DONE? I am using fragment and attaching it to Activity.

Comment: ...nowhere in your initial post did you mention anything about wanting to know when the fragment was done. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: set this to only in your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

do this way,

Set you landing screen by default portrait mode only,

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FirstScreen Activity do like this .

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final int DELAY_MILLISECOND=5000; // Wait for 5 seconds to load
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Changed Orientation to default",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, DELAY_MILLISECOND);

}

}
```